# Unity-How do I make a Temporary Power-up?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making an overhead shooter game, and I made it so when the player touches a certain object, their fire rate increases. How can I make it so the power up wears off after a few seconds?

```
public class PlayerPickups : MonoBehaviour {

PlayerHealth playerHealth;

public float RFBoostValue=0.005f;

GameObject player;

void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        playerHealth = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
    }

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{ 

    if (other.tag == "Rapid Fire Pickup")
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        PlayerShooting.timeBetweenBullets -= RFBoostValue;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'd say you need a timer in there somewhere, just not sure where as my knowledge of Unity isn't the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a timer and ckeck it in the Update()

```
    float timer = 0;
    float seconds = 2;

    private void Update() {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if(timer > seconds) {
            timer = 0;
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: or you just add the powerup value, and in `Invoke(string, float)` some function that substracts it again after x seconds. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html

Comment: How would I put that code into an ontriggerenter function?

Comment: @KennethDionisi add a `void RemovePowerup() {...}` function and do your remove powerup logic in there. in `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` you add a line `Invoke("RemovePowerup", 2.0f);` and it will call the function you previously created after 2 seconds. if your player dies make sure you do `CancelInvoke("RemovePowerup");` (you can also check if anything is invoking with `IsInvoking`). alternatively you can use Coroutines (i recommend getting used to them sooner than later, theyre pretty handy for all sorts of stuff)

Comment: @KennethDionisi thinking about it, in the long run youre probably better off if you do it with coroutines, its easier to expand on them.

Answer (score 0):

Dond write `PlayerShooting.timeBetweenBullets -= RFBoostValue;` like. If your player is died or something happens, the data is corrupted.

You need to store a list of IAffect or sothing like this in player component. PlayerAffectController will be controll each affect lifetime. 
And each affect do this code in OnActivate method `PlayerShooting.timeBetweenBullets -= RFBoostValue;` and this `PlayerShooting.timeBetweenBullets += RFBoostValue;` in OnDeactivate.

Comment: OnTriggerEnter() need to add himself to PlayerAffectController

Answer (score 0):

Lets imagine you touch the location that gives you a powerup. At that point I would attach a component to your character or some sort of powerup manager, depends how your game is built.
Inside the powerup component in Update method you could have your powerup apply its effect on gameobject it is attached to, while counting time similarly to how user2953780 posted. After time is up I would remove the component:

```
float timer = 0;
float seconds = 2;

private void Update() 
{
 //Apply powerup effect

 //Count time
 timer += Time.deltaTime;

 if(timer > seconds) 
 {
   //time to remove to powerup component
   Destroy(this);
 }
}
```